# Find account number linked to two different sources

Tags: sql, oracle

I wanted find all account number which are coming from two sources.
Below is details
Table name Transaction
Column: account number, source, date, sales

I'm looking only for two source( abc, xyz) which are having same account number with same sales and date

Not found expected result and not an expert in SQL

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `HAVING` clause after grouping by account and date (since you want them to have the same date).

```
create table transaction (
  account_number integer, 
  source varchar(20), 
  order_date date, 
  sales integer
  );
```

```
insert into transaction values (1, 'abc', to_date('2020-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 200);
insert into transaction values (1, 'xyz', to_date('2020-01-15', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 200);
insert into transaction values (2, 'abc', to_date('2020-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 200);
insert into transaction values (2, 'xyz', to_date('2020-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 200);
insert into transaction values (3, 'abc', to_date('2020-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 200);
insert into transaction values (3, 'abc', to_date('2020-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 200);
```

```
select account_number
from transaction
where source in ('abc', 'xyz')
group by account_number, order_date
having count(distinct source) > 1
```

| ACCOUNT_NUMBER |
| --- |
| 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RlO8wRZX)